# Using Javascript to Remove Duplicated Commas

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I am currently making a program and it has some code that turns all spaces to commas, `string.replace(/\s+/g,',');` but I want to make it also set all sets of commas into one.

Currently, if this data set was to be changed it would go from `1, 2, 3` to `1,,2,,3` but I want it to go to `1,2,3`. Previously I used this code `if (g('txt').value.indexOf(',,')!=-1){var string = g('txt').value,split = string.replace(/,,/g,',');g('txt').value = split;}`, but it only changes sets of two commas, but not if there is 3 or more.

Anybody know how to do that?

**ALSO**

Is there any way to check if there are any letters in the input?

Comment: `/,?\s+,?/g,','`

Comment: that code doesn't fix the issue with the commas, it doesn't actually remove the extras, any idea how to do that?

Comment: It worked for me... `"1, 2, 3".replace(/,?\s+,?/g,',')` I get `"1,2,3"`

Comment: the answer below worked for me, anyway, thanks for helping

Comment: why do it in two steps?

Comment: You added a second question, but you _shouldn’t_ ask multiple questions in one post. The answer to that is: yes, there is a way to check whether there are any letters in the output. Have you tried to find one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: `string.replace(/,+/g,',');`

Comment: @FinleySherwood Glad I could help! Make sure to accept the answer, and, if you feel like it, leave an upvote.

Comment: just needs to wait a few minutes but I will

Answer (score 2):

One step:

```
"1, 2, 3".replace(/,*\s+,*/g,',')
```

or if you want to do it in Two Steps

```
"1, 2, 3".replace(/\s+/g,',').replace(/,+/g, ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code to `str.replace(/,*\s+|\s+,*|,+/g, ",")`.

Examples:

- `"1, 2, 3"`, `"1,2  3"`, `"1,,2, 3"` all change to `"1,2,3"`
- `"1, 2, ,3"` changes to `"1,2,,3"` (assuming a space between two commas shouldn’t be ignored)

If you want the last case to still output `"1,2,3"`, use `/,*\s+,*|,+/g` instead.